# Restricting the permissions for all users of attaching a public IP to EC2/VM in GCP/AWS/Azure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, azure-vm

Is there some policy wherein we can restrict users for attaching public IPs to the VM in all the three clouds.

Answer (score 1):

By using IAM roles and Permissions we can restrict user to attaching a public ip to a VM in GCP

In gcp we have a [Compute Public IP Admin role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.publicIpAdmin) where the only user who has this role will have Full control of public IP address management for Compute Engine.

For more information follow [Compute Engine IAM roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.publicIpAdmin) .

Answer (score 0):

In GCP We can use organization policies to restrict Public IP on VMs.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/limiting-public-ips-google-cloud

Answer (score 0):

In Azure, you can use policies to audit or restrict what can or cannot be done.

The policies can be applied on subscription level or resource group level.

There is a built-in policy named "Network interfaces should not have public IPs"  that does exactly what you describe.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/policy-reference